# How to display an image in map info window of MAP Quest in action script?

Tags: image, actionscript-3, mapquest, mapinfo

I am trying to display an image in Map Info Window together with a text. I am using Map Quest. I wanted to display an image along with the text in the Map Info Window. I am using Map Quest in action script.

```
var stringContent:String = new String();
stringContent += "Map Info Window";
stringContent += "Display Image";
stringContent += "<img src='app-storage:/img123.jpg'/>";
poi.infoContent = (stringContent);
```

I tried to display the image using  tag of HTML. But this does not display the image in the map info window. The image is saved in application storage directory.

```
http://developer.mapquest.com/content/as/v/mq/samples/samplesexplorer/index.html#samplegroup=PoisAndInfoWindows&sample=PoiWithHTMLInfoWindow
```

I referred the above link for displaying the image in the map info window.